# Return deleted docs data returns undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I am using Google Cloud Function, but since it runs on a older version of Node, I can not use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46799169/return-all-docs-when-all-docs-are-deleted-in-a-collection-in-firestore) answer anymore. I want a function that will batch delete all the documents in a collection and returns the data from it. This is my attempt:

```
function deleteCollectionAndReturnResults(db, collectionRef, batchSize) {
  var query = collectionRef.limit(batchSize);
  return deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, []);
}

function deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, results) {
  return query.get().then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.size == 0) return 0;
    var batch = db.batch();
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => { 
      if (doc.exists) {results.push(doc);}
      batch.delete(doc.ref); 
    });
    return batch.commit().then(() => snapshot.size);
  }).then(function(numDeleted) {
    if (numDeleted >= batchSize) {
      return deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, results);
    }else{
      return results
    }
  });
}
```

But when I run it like this:

```
exports.tester = functions.firestore.document('x/{x}').onCreate(event => {
      deleteCollectionAndReturnResults(db, db.collection("x"), 100).then(docs => {
        console.log(docs)
      })
})
```

This is my output:

[image]

Is there something wrong why I do get the 'function returned undefined'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tester` function doesn't return anything.  Instead, it should return a promise that's resolved when all the work is complete.  It looks like you've simply forgotten to return the promise returned by `deleteCollectionAndReturnResults`:

```
exports.tester = functions.firestore.document('x/{x}').onCreate(event => {
    return deleteCollectionAndReturnResults(db, db.collection("x"), 100).then(docs => {
        console.log(docs)
    })
})
```